# Mocking a return value in a sub object

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I want to write a test case for a feature within complex data structures. The feature doesn't rely on all the data and getting real instances with the desired properties is hard. Hence, I am using Mocks.

```
def test_Case:
    t1 = Timeseries(...) # Data
    t2 = Timeseries(...) # Data

    fancy_t1 = Mock(data=d1, additional_property= ...)
    fancy_t2 = Mock(data=d2, additional_property= ...)

    container = Mock(data_sets=[fancy_t1, fancy_t2])

    ret = function_to_test(container)
    assert ret ... # Some condition
```

Within `function_to_test` there is a call of the form

```
container.aggregation.aggregate(fancy_t, more_arguments1, more_arguments2, ... )
```

What I want the `aggregation.aggregate` call to do is quite simple. It is supposed to evaluate to `t1+t2` (a Timeseries) and ignore the `fancy_t` and the other arguments.

How would I do that?

If I do something like this

```
agg = Mock()
agg.return_value = d1 + d2
container.aggregation.get_aggregated_positions = agg
```

It evalutes to something like `<Mock name='mock.aggregation.get_aggregated_positions()' id='296569680'>` instead of a Timeseries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that works:

```
from mock import patch

with patch('package.container.aggregation.get_aggregated_positions', return_value=_fake_fnc()):
   ret = function_to_test(container)
   assert ret ... # Some condition

def _fake_fnc():
   return 0.0
```